# PdfAConformanceException while adding link(anchor) to a document iText5.5.6

Tags: java, itext, pdfa

I have the following example and i am coming across `Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAConformanceException: Annotation of type /Link should have Contents key.` `Exception`.
I am trying to add some text as link(anchor) in the `PDF` document with external link.
Is there any issue with my approach of adding the link(anchor)?
Am i missing anything?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.Anchor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.text.List;
import com.itextpdf.text.ListItem;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ICC_Profile;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAConformanceLevel;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.xml.xmp.DublinCoreProperties;
import com.itextpdf.text.xml.xmp.PdfProperties;
import com.itextpdf.text.xml.xmp.XmpWriter;
import com.itextpdf.xmp.XMPException;


public class SquareBullet {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException, XMPException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfAWriter writer = PdfAWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("list.pdf"), PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1A);
        writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfAWriter.PageModeUseOutlines);
        writer.setRunDirection(PdfAWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR);
        writer.setTagged(PdfAWriter.markAll);
        writer.createXmpMetadata();
        XmpWriter xmp = writer.getXmpWriter();

        DublinCoreProperties.addSubject(xmp.getXmpMeta(), "Subject");
        DublinCoreProperties.setTitle(xmp.getXmpMeta(), "Title", "en_US", "en_US");
        DublinCoreProperties.setDescription(xmp.getXmpMeta(), "Description", "en_US", "en_US");
        PdfProperties.setKeywords(xmp.getXmpMeta(), "Keywords");
        PdfProperties.setVersion(xmp.getXmpMeta(), "1.4");
        document.addLanguage("en_US");
        document.open();
        Font font = FontFactory.getFont("ZapfDingbats.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 8);
        Font font1 = FontFactory.getFont("ROsanswebtextregular.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 12);
        ICC_Profile icc = ICC_Profile.getInstance(new FileInputStream("sRGB Color Space Profile.icm"));
        writer.setOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc);
        List list = new List(10);
        Chunk c = new Chunk(String.valueOf((char)110), font);
        list.setListSymbol(c);
        list.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Test 1", font1)));
        list.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Test 2", font1)));
        list.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Test 3", font1)));

        document.add(list);

        Paragraph anchorP = new Paragraph();
        Anchor anchor = new Anchor("Google", font);
        anchor.setReference("https://google.com");
        anchor.setName("Google");
        anchorP.add(anchor);
        document.add(anchorP);

        document.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using the below code, Hope this helps someone!!

```
public class SquareBullet {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException, XMPException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfAWriter writer = PdfAWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("list.pdf"), PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1A);
        writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfAWriter.PageModeUseOutlines);
        writer.setRunDirection(PdfAWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR);
        writer.setTagged(PdfAWriter.markAll);
        writer.createXmpMetadata();
        XmpWriter xmp = writer.getXmpWriter();

        DublinCoreProperties.addSubject(xmp.getXmpMeta(), "Subject");
        DublinCoreProperties.setTitle(xmp.getXmpMeta(), "Title", "en_US", "en_US");
        DublinCoreProperties.setDescription(xmp.getXmpMeta(), "Description", "en_US", "en_US");
        PdfProperties.setKeywords(xmp.getXmpMeta(), "Keywords");
        PdfProperties.setVersion(xmp.getXmpMeta(), "1.4");
        document.addLanguage("en_US");
        document.open();
        Font font1 = FontFactory.getFont("ROsanswebtextregular.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 12);
        ICC_Profile icc = ICC_Profile.getInstance(new FileInputStream("sRGB Color Space Profile.icm"));
        writer.setOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc);

        Chunk c = new Chunk("Google", font1);
        PdfAction action = new PdfAction("https://google.com");

        PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.createLink(
                writer, new Rectangle(0 ,0), PdfName.HIGHLIGHT,
                action);
        annotation.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, PdfName.TEXT);
        annotation.setBorderStyle(new PdfBorderDictionary(0, PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_BEVELED));
        c.setAnnotation(annotation);
        document.add(c);
        document.close();
    }
}
```